# How can get object data that I've set in chrome.storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm building a Chrome extension and I'm trying to use Chrome's ability to store objects with their chrome.storage API. I've successfully been able to set an object but when I try to get it, I can't seem to do it. This is likely less of an issue with chrome.storage and more to do with my inexperience with getting data from JSON objects.

Here is the code I'm using to set the object in storage.

```
  var ids = { "a":1234, "b":5678 };
  var obj= {};
  var key = "MyChromeKey";
  obj[key] = ids;
  chrome.storage.sync.set(obj);
```

When I use `.get` the object appears in my console just like I expect it to. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get, for example, the value of `a` from it.

```
  chrome.storage.sync.get(key,function(result){
    console.log(key,result);      // MyChromeKey > Object {MyChromeKey: Object}
    console.log(result["a"]);     // undefined
    console.log(key,result["a"]); // MyChromeKey undefined
  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about `result["a"]`?

Comment: Returns `undefined`

Comment: try chrome.storage.sync.get("a", function(result) { console.log(result) });

Comment: Just returns an empty object.

Comment: Oh it looks like it may be nested actually. `result["MyChromeKey"]["a"]`

Comment: That did the trick! `console.log(result[key]["a"]);` also works so I can use my variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's storage API will return an object that will be in the form { "yourKeyName" : Object }, so to access a value inside that object you will have to first go through the "yourKeyName" level and then access the underlying object. EDIT: The reason it returns it in this format is because "you can give an array of keys, and it returns an object with the values of all those keys." (Thanks SO user [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)!)

`result["MyChromeKey"]["a"]` will work for your code.

Comment: The reason is that you can give an array of keys, and it returns an object with the values of all those keys. A single key is just treated like an array of 1 key.

Answer (score 0):

The result parameter of your `callback` function is a standard `Javascript` object.

If all you want is to log it out to the console, try the following in the `callback` function:

```
console.log(result[key]);
```